# Can a curve be an asymptote?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics, infinity

$f(x)=x^3+\frac{3}{x-1}$

This was the question given to me. I replied that $f(x)$ will have only a single vertical asymptote of $x=1$.

My teacher told that there'll be be two asymptotes. One is the vertical one($x=1$) and another is the curve $y=x^3$.

I checked on the Internet and except for [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Asymptote.html), which includes curve in its definition of asymptotes, every other site defines asymptote as a line.

Can a curve be an asymptote?

Comment: It's a question of terminology. One certainly says $f(x)$ is asymptotic to $x^3$ as $x\to\infty$. Whether one says $x^3$ is an asymptote for $f(x)$ is, I think, a matter of what definition you find convenient to use.

Comment: Seconding Gerry Myerson's point: this is purely a matter of convention. Most common is that only straight lines are asymptotes, because otherwise there would always be an uncountable infinity of asymptotes to _any_ curve. E.g., $y=x$ would have asymptotes $y=x+{c\over x^n}$ for every $n=1,2,3, ...$ and every constant $c$ which seems a bit pointless, not what the word is intended to convey. Really means a _simpler_ curve that is closer-and-closer-at-infinity. Still, we'd need to clarify "simpler". Straight lines are simple... :)

Comment: Simul-posted to, and very quickly closed at, MO, with notice neither here nor there. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139911/can-a-curve-be-an-asymptote

Comment: @Gerry Sir:I'm the one who has posted it there.I wasn't sure whether it's research oriented or not.

Comment: Questions about high school mathematics are rarely research questions, but that's not the problem; the problem is, you posted the same question two places without telling either one you were doing that. Don't you think it would have been polite to tell each site that you had posted to the other?

Comment: @Gerry Sir:I'm really sorry.It won't repeat again.

Comment: Wikipedia defines an asymptote as "a line such that the distance between the curve and the line approaches zero as they tend to infinity." It mentions that modern usage allows the curve to "cross the line infinitely often." It also mentions "curvilinear asymptotes", but, "the term asymptote by itself is usually reserved for linear asymptotes.".

Comment: We can only assume the instructor knows what definitions were given in that course.  And those of us here don't.

Answer (score 1):

Our definition of asymptote:

> Let $f$ be a real function defined on some neighborhood of $\infty$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. We say the function $ax + b$ is the asymptote of that function if $$\lim_{x \to\infty} (f(x) - ax - b) = 0.$$

(The definition of asymptote in $-\infty$ is analogous.)

In our definition, only the affine function $ax + b$ can be asymptote. What you call an asymptote (vertical line $x = 1$) we do not call asymptote at all.

That being said, it is a matter of definition and what you need this for. At high school during precalculus lessons, we used to call an asymptote everything "the function value tends to at the function plot".